# How to use callbacks with cplexAPI in R

Tags: r, cplex

I am using the cplexAPI package of R to solve mixed-integer problems in the cplex environment. I have already successfully written the problem, getting the final optimal solution, and now I would like to get the internal solutions of the branch and bound tree. I guess that I must use the callbacks, but I do not know how to implement it in R. For the other functions/instructions, many examples can be found in the tutorial of the cplexAPI for R. However, no example exists for the callbacks. Could anyone help me?

Many thanks

Comment: It seems that the callback functions are not implemented in cplexAPI https://github.com/cran/cplexAPI/search?q=callback&unscoped_q=callback

Comment: Dear Gorka, many thanks for your prompt help. Alternatively to cplexAPI, I tried to write the MIP model in OPL (used in R by an external call), but I also could not implement the callbacks. They also cannot be implemented in OPL? 
If the callbacks cannot be implemented in R (neither by cplexAPI nor by OPL), do you know if it is possible and how to get at least a set of feasible solutions of the MIP model (not only the optimal solution)?

Comment: I don't know how could be obtained in R. Perhaps, if you are in an early development stage, you should consider to use one of the [programming languages with examples listed in the cplex help page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/examplescplex.html).

Comment: If you only want to do this to get a set of feasible solutions then I suggest you rephrase your question or open a new one. In CPLEX there is the solution pool which gives you access to all the solutions that CPLEX found in the tree. This can be accessed in OPL as well. In OPL you can also post-process every feasible solution. Since you started from R I suggest to check whether cplexAPI supports the functions that query the solution pool.

Comment: Hi,
Many thanks for your suggestions. My current algorithm is not  in an early development stage, so I would like tottery and finish the resolution of the current problem in R.

I guess that the pool of feasible solutions may result as well. Also, OPL seems to be a good alternative, since it can be used in R by external call. Regarding the cplexAPI package, I had already contacted the developers, but I had no answers.